# Powershell Issue: Trying to run an install script for a non administrative user

Tags: powershell, remote-access

Say I have a script: Install.ps1

As an admin, I want to be able to run this script for a specified user: joe.smith

Joe.smith is not an admin.
All of this should be done on localhost, no need to remote to a different computer.

Things I've tried:

```
new-pssession localhost -credential SSN314\joe.smith
```

Error: new-pssession : [localhost] Connecting to remote server localhost failed with the following error message : Access is
denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

Also I've tried:

```
$username = "joe.smith"
$password = "pass"
$secstr = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
$password.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secstr.AppendChar($_)}
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $secstr
Invoke-Command -FilePath "C:\dir\Install.ps1" -Credential $cred -ComputerName "."
```

Joe.smith is not an admin, which is why I think I'm getting the access denied error.

joe.smith is a domain account.

joe.smith has full control when I run the : Set-PSSessionConfiguration -ShowSecurityDescriptorUI -Name Microsoft.Powershell command

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue as I see it is you are trying to remote to the local PC. You should be able to use `Start-Process` instead.

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-file","C:\dir\Install.ps1" -Credential $cred
```

Comment: Now its saying my directory name is invalid when it clearly is not.